# How to test if a URL is fired when the user clicks on a button using Rspec/Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rspec, capybara

I have a button in my Rails application `Download CSV`. On clicking that, a CSV file gets downloaded on the user's machine in the "Downloads" folder. The browser url does not change but through `HttpFox` (an Http sniffer tool) I can see following url getting fired

**URL 1 : Download CVS Button click URL**

```
GET /csv.csv?utf8=%E2%9C%93&csv_export_limit=10000&commit=Download+CSV HTTP/1.1
```

**URL 2: Browser URL**

`http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&start_time=04%2F01%2F2016+12%3A00+AM&end_time=04%2F30%2F2016+12%3A00+AM&store_id=&payment_session_id=&account_id=&transaction_amount=&iso_currency_code=&commit=Search&show_results=true`

In my rspec/capybara test how can I test if `URL 1` is getting fired? So far I have the following spec already written but have not been able to figure out the last step.

**download_csv_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.feature 'Transaction Search' do

  scenario ' - Download CSV scenario' do
    visit '/signin'
    fill_in 'Email', :with => 'user@payments.org'
    fill_in 'Password', :with => 'Password123'
    page.find('#login').click

    # search page
    visit '/search'
    expect(page).to have_content("Search")
    click_button 'Search'
    puts 'Search button clicked'
    click_button 'Download CSV'
    puts 'Download CSV button clicked'

  end

end
```

**download_csv_controller.rb**

```
 def csvexport
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { send_data export_to_csv(fetch_csv_records), filename: "transactions-#{Date.today}.csv" }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you necessarily need to check that specific URL? Otherwise you can just check that you are downloading a csv file like this: `expect(page.response_headers['Content-Type']).to be("text/csv")` and you can further test the contents of the csv file like it's described on this other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309324/how-to-test-csv-file-download-in-capybara-and-rspec)

Comment: If the intent is that you want to be sure the user has actually downloaded the CSV, 
You could even do something like: `expect_any_instance(DownloadCsvController).to receive(:send_data).with(...)`

Comment: Also consider the options presented in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309324/how-to-test-csv-file-download-in-capybara-and-rspec and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164255/downloading-a-csv-using-capybara